# C:copying multiple files into one

Tags: c

I am stuck/struggling with a problem I am trying  in C(Linux) using API calls(only) to copy multiple input files via command line into one output file. I have searched the Internet for answers but none seem to solve.
My program allows me to specify multiple input files and one output file via the command line.  For example:

```
./archiver file1.txt file2 file3 file4 outputfile
```

I read these parameters using `argc`/`argv`.  For some reason when I do `ls -l`, `./archiver` and `outputfile` have the same number of bytes, thus meaning none of my input files have been copied to my outputfile, just whatever was in memory (when I do `cat outputfile` it shows a bunch of  these )

None of the contents from my input files are in my output files.

Please could you help me as after those bunch of "" I don't know what to do I have tried reading up on `malloc()` etc. but I don't know how to implement that or if thats even relevant here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

```
file_desc_in = open(argv[i],O_RDONLY,0);    
//NEED a loop to copy multiple files in...  
while (!eof) {
     bytes_read = read(file_desc_in, &buffer, sizeof(buffersize)); 

     if (bytes_read > 1)
         bytes_written = write(file_desc_out, &i, bytes_read);
     else {
         eof=1;
     }
```

I haven't included the errors but I do have them. Thanks for replying immediately.

Comment: Post some code, otherwise it's impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: I suspect that this is a homework assignment -- if so you should tag it as such. Your question is very unclear -- I think that you are frustrated and perhaps your assignment is already late, but please try to be clear so we know how to help. Are you trying to concatenate several files, or are you trying to store them in such a way that you can easily separate them back out into the original files again later?

Comment: Do you have an outer loop, using `i`?

Comment: Are you trying to do the equivalent of `cat file1 file2 file3 >outfile`?

Comment: Why are you writing i in your output file instead of buffer ?.

Comment: yes loadmaster thats what I'm trying to do. and nategoose I want to store them in such away that I can easily separate them back out into the original files. Fre-yes I do have an outer loop so I can read in multiple files.  and LuisG.CR. when I try buffer it changes my ouput file into anothe file extension whereas when I do i it changes it to binary. Sorry for being so unclear.

Comment: I understand why I cant copy contents from file1 file2 file3 into the ouput file. This is because after further reading, my read an write  commands were wrong, know they work. When I was opening my input file I was opening i, it was initialized to 0 and in my variables hence my file printed out what was in i which was my ./archiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd help to see your code. There's not a lot here to go on, but I'm going to take a wild guess. I suspect you're copying the file specified by `argv[0]` (your program) and not getting the rest. I don't think I can do any better with what you've given.

Comment: I think you may be right I'm using i too many times for alot of stuff so I will double check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You say you are only using API calls.  What API are you talking about?  The POSIX API?  The standard C file I/O API?

If you are just combining input files, you don't really need to write a C program to do it.  Since you are running Linux, try using the shell command `cat input1 input2 input3 > output`.

If you must write a C program to do it, start simple.  Before you actually do any file I/O, make sure that you can interpret the input arguments correctly.  Have your program simply read in the command-line input and print out something like this:

```
Input files: file1.txt file2.txt file2.txt
Output files: outputfile.txt
```

That way, you can verify that your CLI parsing code works correctly before you start worrying about file I/O.  It's much easier to debug things one piece at a time.

Comment: sorry I meant POSIX API in my head it was clear, but I forget to mention.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop needs to open each filename, and close it at the end of the loop. You close the output file at the very end, after all the input files are read.

You should also learn the difference between `open`, `read`, `write` and `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`.